# Regex for free form textbox amount validation (XX.XX) within open and close parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Valid values:

```
50,
50.00,
(50),
(2),
(50.00),
(10.XX),
```

some invalid examples:

```
(50,
((50,
50)),
60),
50.),
```

Comment: Post the rules instead of examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
^\(\d+(\.\d{2})?\)$|^\d+(\.\d{2})?$
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/oK8rZ3/4)

Comment: The requirement here is it should not match and give error if he enters invalid amount like ((50, 50)), (50., (((40. I dont think the above is working.The valid ones are (XX.XX) or (XX). Please help

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the format is ##.##, with two digits max, and an optional decimal with maybe 1 or two more numbers, and the whole shebang maybe surrounded by parens to indicate negative. I'm also assuming 10.XX isn't really valid, but replacing the X's with numbers would be.

I'd recommend separate negative and positive regexes so that your code is clear. E.g.:

```
good = ["50", "50.00", "(50)", "(2)", "(50.00)", "(10.19)"];
bad = ["(50", "((50", "50))", "60)", "50.)"];
posRegex = /^\d\d?(\.\d{0,2})?$/;
negRegex = /^\(\d\d?(\.\d{0,2})?\)$/;

function matches(val) {
    var m = posRegex.test(val) || negRegex.test(val);
    console.log(val + " : " + m);
}

console.log("These should be true");
good.forEach(matches);

console.log("These should be false");
bad.forEach(matches);
```